# What's the difference between 謹賀新年, 明けましておめでとうございます, and 新年おめでとうございます, as New Year's greetings?

Tags: greetings

Aside from translation differences, I was never sure of what distinguishes them from each other. Anyone else know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same. [They are many set phrases to celebrate a happy new year](https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/220632/), and your examples are only some of the most popular ones. But all-kanji versions would look stiffer, and they are meant to be written/printed on 年賀状. In speech, you can stick to 明けましておめでとうございます everywhere.